# Slow delivery of Firebase Push Notifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Cloud Functions which listen for Firestore changes and send push notifications accordingly. However these notifications are very slow. They arrive to end user with almost a minute delay. For chat application which I'm creating is not so good and should be instantly.

This is the code from Cloud function which does listening and sending the notification:

```
              admin.firestore()
              .collection('users')
              .where('id', '==', idFrom)
              .get()
              .then(querySnapshot2 => {
                querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
                  console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().nickname}`)
                  const payload = {
                    notification: {
                      title: `You have a message from "${userFrom.data().nickname}"`,
                      body: contentMessage,
                      priority: 'high',
                      badge: '1',
                      sound: 'mytone'
                    }
                  }
                  // push to the target device
                  admin
                    .messaging()
                    .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      console.log('Error sending message:', error)
                    })
                })
              })
```

Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Are you using FCM to send the actual chat messages between the chat participants, or are you simply notifying one recipient that they have a message on the database that they should read?

Comment: I'm just notifiying recipient. In a notification last message is shown as well.

Comment: Ok. In my experience FCM notifications are never instantaneous nor are they intended to be. Also, the cloud function may not be firing immediately either. Having said that, a minute delay is long, I normally see something in a couple of seconds.

Comment: Any alternative?

Comment: I'm happy with my responses for notifications so haven't looked at other options. As long as my chat messages are pretty much instant when both participants are in the app, then I'm happy...and so are they.

Comment: If you are waiting a minute consistently then I would look for issues in your code, set some timers, prints, etc. May also depend on where you are in the world.

Comment: I've changed region to Europe and still no improvements. Maybe something in the code is producing delay...

Comment: I have a similar problem with admin.messaging().sendToDevice. I am sending only important, punctual events with just 2 small strings in the playload to users ,like when they are invited in a new group, and the call to sendToDevice can take up to 3min in the logs to complete. I do not see what I can optimize in my function code. It's not ruining my user experience, but it's a pain to debug!

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the delay is due to FCM's interval of sending out push notifications as mentioned on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854943/slow-delivery-of-firebase-push-notifications). This behavior can't be solved on the client-side.